# where to define?

Tags: admin, theme, css, frontend

im a rookie with magento, but did the first steps in the backend and defined some look and feel in the css file from the implemented theme

But now i stock in the defining of some on the frontend.

on the site www.ungezogen-angezogen.ch is in a / div=footer-container

is some text defined but i cant finde it on my server

can u help me out where to finde ? in the back end theres nothing where i can change it exept the ©2014 ungezogen-angezogen.ch  - ..........

would be great if anyone could help me

kind regads from a rookie

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things like Copyright (which is the item you mentioned "©2014 ungezogen-angezogen.ch - .........") that display in the footer that are edited in the admin.  To change most things in the footer you will need to edit the template (.phtml) files in your theme.

The div with a class of 'footer-container' is in this file:

> app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\page\html\footer.phtml

You can check in the admin System -> Configuration -> Design (tab) -> Package and Theme drop downs if you need to look up the package and theme names used on the site.

Comment: Hello Jason big thanks for your short help. I found the file changed it local and upload it to the server, but nothing happend. I saw that the phone numme gett a echo in php from somewhere, so could it be theres a connection that will overwrite the file? For better understanding you can see the footer.php and 3 pictures (sysconfig1.png..sysconfig2.png ..sysconfig3.png ) under shooting.bplaced.net/magentofiles/

Comment: sorry for disturbing u, its donne, the server had tooo long to refresh pageview, but now its all okay . again a big thank you from a rookie, u made my day :-9

Comment: You're very welcome Sven.  If this answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.